Custom Credential Provider Stopped Working After Logging Mechanism Change
I have a custom credential provider that was previously using the eventcreate process to log messages. However, after making changes to the logging mechanism, the credential provider has stopped working altogether.
Previous Logging Mechanism (Working):
The original logging function looked like this:
template <typename... Args>
static void debug(const char* format, Args... args)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(Log::m_smutex);

    if (Log::isLogEnabled())
    {

        char command[] = "eventcreate.exe /t information /id 1 /l application /d ";

        int length = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format, args...);

        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[length + 1]);
        std::snprintf(buf.get(), length + 1, format, args...);

        length = static_cast<int>(strlen(command) + strlen(buf.get()) + 3);

        std::unique_ptr<char[]> proc(new char[length]);

        strcpy_s(proc.get(), length, command);
        strcat_s(proc.get(), length, "\"");
        strcat_s(proc.get(), length, buf.get());
        strcat_s(proc.get(), length, "\"");

        STARTUPINFOA si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        CreateProcessA(NULL, proc.get(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        // Close process and thread handles.
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}

On Windows 11 this credential provider is showing inconsistent behaviour, where a user is sometimes able to log in the Windows and sometimes cannot. The same credential provider works on all Windows Servers and Windows 10 without any problem. So, while debugging I saw that for logs this existing credential provider creates Windows eventcreate process and uses WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); to wait for the process result. I thought that maybe there's privilege issue which might be causing the credential provider to misbehave because it might not be able to create eventcreate process OR it might be waiting for process to finish indefinitely because of WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); line in the code.
So to simplify this I just rewrote the logger function as below.
template <typename... Args>
static void debug(const char* format, Args... args)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(Log::m_smutex);
    Log::getLogPath();
    std::string logFilePath(fullLogPath);

    std::ofstream logFileStream(logFilePath, std::ios_base::app);

    if (!logFileStream.fail())
    {
        std::string logMessage = fmt::format(format, args...);

        logFileStream << logMessage << std::endl;
        logFileStream.flush();
        logFileStream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open log file: " << logFilePath << std::endl;
    }
}

Issue:
Since switching to the new logging mechanism, the credential provider no longer functions at all, whereas previously with the old logging mechanism it sometimes worked and sometimes did not.\
Note
With the new logger I can see that logging is being done correctly but the credential provider stops functioning 100% of the time. Whereas with the old logging mechanism the credential provider sometimes worked and sometimes did not, like 50-50.
Questions:
What could be causing the credential provider to stop functioning after changing the logging mechanism?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The first solution is absolutely monstrous. create a new process for each new log entry?! and why even wait for its completion. Well, in order to find out why the dll stopped working, you just need to know how to use a debugger

@RbMm Yeah! I would use a debugger but a separate DLL (call it ADLL) is responsible for passing credential to it, which is loaded by a Java process and through JNI credentials are passed to the ADLL, which in turn creates a NamedPipe server and writes credentials on it so that the Credential Provider DLL can read them and login into Windows through a console session. These two DLL are tiny part of large distributed system.
On top of all these Microsoft has removed download link from remote debugger for Visual Studio 2019, which is used here.

no any problem (for me) debug LogonUI process from local system. fmt::format(format, args...); probably crased . debugger say when and where.

I forgot to add one detail that is, with the new logger I can see that logging is being done correctly but the credential provider stops functioning 100% of the time. Whereas with the old logging mechanism the credential provider sometimes worked and sometimes did not, like 50-50.

again - need use debugger
